# GridView with SqlDataSource: Update does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm using the auto generated edit feature of GridView. The edit button appears, clicking it enters edit mode but making changes and clicking update does nothing (that I can tell). The database does not update. Through testing it seems that OnRowEditing triggers but OnRowUpdating does not. INSERT, SELECT and DELETE all work perfectly. I have tested my UpdateCommand on the SQL database directly and it works as intended.

Why does this not work? I've been searching for answers for days now.

Here is the full code in its current state:

```
<%@ Page Language="C# " AutoEventWireup="true"%>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data.Common" %>
<%@Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
    private void InsertDomain(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.Insert();
    }
    private void OnDomainDeleted(Object source, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = e.AffectedRows + " row(s) were deleted";
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = 5;
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool x = e.Cancel;
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = e.AffectedRows;
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Domain Manager</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Label
        id="Label1"
        runat="server"
        forecolor="Red" />

    <h1>Godaddy</h1>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:SqlDataSource
            id="SqlDataSource1"
            runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLconnect %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DomainName,InUse FROM DomainList"
            UpdateCommandType="Text"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE DomainList SET InUse=@InUse WHERE (DomainName=@DomainName)"
            DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM DomainList WHERE DomainName=@DomainName"
            OnDeleted="OnDomainDeleted">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="DomainName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="InUse" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView
            id="GridView1"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            DataKeyNames="DomainName"
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
            AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true"
            EnableViewState="true"
            ViewStateMode="Enabled"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            AllowSorting="true"
            OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
            OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
            OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated">
            <rowstyle backcolor="LightCyan"  
                   forecolor="Black" />
            <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="PaleTurquoise"  
                  forecolor="Black" />
            <columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Domain Name" DataField="DomainName" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="DomainName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="In Use" DataField="InUse" SortExpression="InUse" />
                <%--<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Domain Cost" DataField="DomainCost" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="TLD" DataField="TLD" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Registrar" DataField="Registrar" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expiration Date" DataField="ExpirationDate" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Privacy" DataField="Privacy" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Forwarding URL" DataField="ForwardingURL" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Notes" DataField="Notes" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Department/Program" DataField="DepartmentProgram" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Program Contact" DataField="ProgramContact" />--%>
            </columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <hr />

        <asp:SqlDataSource
            id="SqlDataSource2"
            runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLconnect %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM DomainList"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO DomainList (DomainName,InUse,DomainCost,TLD,Registrar,ExpirationDate,Status, 
                                    Privacy,ForwardingURL,Notes,DepartmentProgram,ProgramContact) VALUES (@DName,@IUse,@DCost,
                                    @TLD,@Registrar,@ExDate,@Status,@Privacy,@FURL,@Notes,@Dept,@PContact)" >
                <insertparameters>
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="DName" FormField="DomainNameBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="IUse" FormField="InUseBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="DCost" FormField="DomainCostBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="TLD" FormField="TLDBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="Registrar" FormField="RegistrarBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="ExDate" FormField="ExDateBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="Status" FormField="StatusBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="Privacy" FormField="PrivacyBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="FURL" FormField="FURLBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="Notes" FormField="NotesBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="Dept" FormField="DeptBox" />
                    <asp:FormParameter Name="PContact" FormField="PContactBox" />
                </insertparameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <h1>Create New Godaddy Domain: </h1>

        <br />Domain Name: <asp:TextBox
            id="DomainNameBox"
            runat="server" />

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="DomainNameBox"
            Display="Static"
            ErrorMessage="You must enter a domain name" />

        <br />In Use? (yes/no): <asp:TextBox
            id="InUseBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Cost: <asp:TextBox
            id="DomainCostBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />TLD: <asp:TextBox
            id="TLDBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Registrar: <asp:TextBox
            id="RegistrarBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Expiration Date: <asp:TextBox
            id="ExDateBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Status: <asp:TextBox
            id="StatusBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Privacy: <asp:TextBox
            id="PrivacyBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Forwarding URL: <asp:TextBox
            id="FURLBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Notes: <asp:TextBox
            id="NotesBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Department: <asp:TextBox
            id="DeptBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br />Program Contact: <asp:TextBox
            id="PContactBox"
            runat="server" />

        <br /><asp:Button
            id="Button1"
            runat="server"
            text="Create New Domain"
            onclick="InsertDomain" />

        <hr />

        <h1>Network Solutions</h1>

        <asp:GridView
            id="GridView2"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
            DataKeyNames="DomainName"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
            <rowstyle backcolor="LightCyan"  
                   forecolor="Black"
                   />
                <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="PaleTurquoise"  
                  forecolor="Black"
                  />
            <columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Domain Name" DataField="DomainName" ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Account" DataField="AccountNo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Points To" DataField="PointsTo" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Folder" DataField="Folder" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Auto Renew" DataField="AutoRenew" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Expiration Date" DataField="ExpirationDate" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="WHOIS Admin" DataField="AdminContact" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="WHOIS Tech" DataField="TechContact" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Account Holder" DataField="AccountHolder" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Private" DataField="Private" />
            </columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            id="SqlDataSource3"
            runat="server"
            DataSourceMode="DataReader"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLconnect%>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DomainName,AccountNo,PointsTo,Private,Folder,AutoRenew,ExpirationDate, 
                                AdminContact,TechContact,AccountHolder FROM NetworkSolutions"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE NetworkSolutions SET AccountNo=@AccountNo,PointsTo=@PointsTo,Private=@Private,Folder=@Folder,AutoRenew=@AutoRenew,ExpirationDate=@ExpirationDate,
                            AdminContact=@AdminContact,TechContact=@TechContact,AccountHolder=@AccountHolder WHERE (DomainName=@DomainName)">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

SOLUTION: I had a function `InsertDomain` that seemed to be catching the updates from the GridViews. Solution required setting a `ValidationGroup` to restrict that validation from affecting the whole page.

Comment: what if you add the following to your Update parameters in the markup 
`Direction="Input"`

Comment: Can you please post the CREATE SCRIPT for the table `DomainList`? I am pretty sure it has something to do with the data type in database.

Comment: To get this script, you can go to the DomainList table in `SQL Server Management Studio`, right-click and then `Script Table as` > `Create to`.

Comment: @MethodMan Didn't work. Looks like `Input` is the default value anyway.

Comment: Ok. Great. Let me check out with your new script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the data type of `InUse` parameter in `SqlDataSource` matches the data type of same column in database.

If this column is of string type in database like varchar or nvarchar, then your update will happen since you have specified the data type as `string` in your SqlDataSource. Otherwise it will be an issue.

After you posted your full page code, I noticed that the validator has no `ValidationGroup` mentioned, and as a result the `Update` button in gridview is not posting back when there is no entry in the text box.  Replace the validator and button markup by following code and it should work then.

```
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            id="RequiredFieldValidator1"
            runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="DomainNameBox"
            Display="Static"
            ErrorMessage="You must enter a domain name"  ValidationGroup="Insert"  />
<asp:Button
            id="Button1"
            runat="server"
            text="Create New Domain"
            onclick="InsertDomain" ValidationGroup="Insert" />
```

Also, if you see an error message that says 'WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping..' then include following appsetting in the web config file.

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Comment: InUse in SQL is nchar(3). That should work with `string` right?

Comment: Can you change that to varchar(3)? Also, before doing this, can you tell me if you see any error on clicking Update in grid view?

Comment: I changed it to varchar(3) but it still doesn't work. And no, there's no error messages.

Comment: Then something else is happening. I tried the exact same scenario as yours except there was no `OnDeleted` event of SqlDataSource and it worked perfectly. I am guessing that there is something in your code-behind that is cancelling the UPDATE command of grid.  Can you post your code-behind if its not too huge?

Comment: Can you try what I have just mentioned in my answer? I am curious what values you see for e.Cancel and e.AffectedRows.

Comment: Also, the property of SqlDataSource called `UpdateCommandType` should be `Text`. I would make sure that this is there.

Comment: Added `UpdateCommandType="Text"` and the provided Row code behind. Debug doesn't show anything for `x`, just says `Unable to evaluate the expression`.

Comment: You can refresh the item in Watch window or just note the values of e.Cancel and e.AffectedRows. Also, shut down all other debugging sessions you have running.

Comment: With the new code behind both `x` and `e` are never given data, breakpoints set there don't trigger. When I create one for `GridView1_RowEditing` it does work and I get values. I'm fairly confident that `GridView_RowUpdating` just does not trigger for some reason.

Comment: They should fire. Check if any ids in your markup are duplicated. Also, set the GridView EnableViewState property to true and ViewStateMode='Enabled'.

Comment: If you have a master page make sure no ids are duplicated across the master and content pages.

Comment: What is the value of `AutoEventWireup` for the page in which the gridview is there?

Comment: Can you post the `Page` markup that is always at the top of every page.

Comment: This looks like  `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"``.

Comment: I set the view states to true and double checked the ids. I had no AutoEventWireup so I set that to true. Still no change.

Comment: I think you need to post your full code else it might be impossible to resolve your situation.

Comment: Great. Let me run your code on my laptop and will get back in 5 minutes.

Comment: Your validators are coming in the way of Update command. I am looking to fix that.

Comment: Incorporate the latest code I have just posted into your page and it should work.